# Animated TV show. Main character called Lock uses gems to summon monsters.

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this years ago. I remember the main character was called Lock and he had to use these gems/ crystals to summon monsters to help him fight but usually you couldn't summon more than two as it was too much for the person to do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locke_the_Superman

Comment: [Monsuno: Destiny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG6_WIb55o)?

Comment: The monsters, were they trapped inside the "gems" in some way? And they fought each other, didn't they? And the man's name, could it have been Brock rather than Lock?

Comment: @MrLister - Pocket monsters, perhaps? Did he feel the urge to "catch them all"?

Comment: sorry guys, I think I have got this one.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

You are thinking about [Huntik: Secrets & Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik), an animated series originally developed in Italy.

> The series follows **Lok Lambert** as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.[4] Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor [cut]

Titans are controlled by using some "amulets" that basically are gems/stones to which the monster is tied to. Since the summoner creates a bond with the summoned monster and "controls" it telepathically, it is pretty hard to control more than a few at once.