# Anime with a boy hiring a creature from a stone, meets a man named Dante and starts a journey to collect crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am from India, this anime or animated series (I can't remember this was made by the Japan or other countries) was aired between 2009 and 2012 probably in Jetix/Disney XD (but I'm not sure).

This anime starts with a boy (the main character, I forgot his name) who find a stone (or crystal like thing) in his dad's property, his dad was missing that time. Some day he accidentally hire a creature/monster from that stone. Other day some creature attack him and he was saved by his creature and the story begins.

In his journey to solve the mystery he meets a middle aged man 'Dante' (probably that was the name; this is the only character name I can remember). He had also some stone. After that they meet with one girl and a women (one of the girls is same age with the main boy character and probably will become his partner as the story goes on). Another women probably Dante's partner.

Four of them started their journey to collect all the stone/crystal. They are collecting twelve legendary creatures to defend against their enemy. I watched till they collect 4 legendary creatures' stones. This anime is kind of touch with archeological things.

This story kind of matches with 'Kiba' anime series. This animation series name probably between 5 to 6 letters. That  galactic football was also hiring besides this anime series.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Definitely *Huntik* (2009-2012).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers#Broadcast),

> In India, the series' first season aired on Disney XD (India) in 2010.

[image: Huntik still; two teenage girls, one teenage blond boy, one red-haired adult]

There's Lok, the blonde guy who discovered his father's amulet. While studying with a friend (Sophie, the skirt girl on the left), it is revealed that his father, who was missing, may be alive. Lok and his friend go on a quest to find him, based on hints in the father's journal (see picture below). Dante's the red-haired guy.

The dark-haired girl on the right (see above still) is named Zhalia. She was raised by a member of the Organization and acted as a spy for them, even betraying the crew she had come to befriend, but later rejoined them in episode 20, *The Unseen Guide*.

[image: A cartoon diary]

There are creatures known as the Titans, and they're summoned by amulets. Below is a collection of Titans and their amulets. The legendary ones are at the bottom. As for the "archeological" stuff, part of it can be seen when they meet the local titans in Atlantis in episode 21, *Coming of Age* (among others).

[image: Full Titans sheet]

Throughout the series, the kids fight against the evil Organization, whose goal is to rule over the world (such originality !). The Organization seeks a huge, legendary-like Titan to ensure their doomination. So basically, they're like villainous Pokémon teams, but without the catchy name.

Plagiarising my own answers to:

- [Fantasy cartoon show aired in India around 2005-12; main character searches for his father. Involved magic rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188464/)
- [Animated show with character who has a stone that summons creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186121/)
- [Cartoon series with teens and adults summoning monsters, involved five temples in Atlantis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183711/)

Comment: It's me or char design look like "Winx stance" and "Code Lyoko face "?

Comment: @DragandDrop a bit, but the forehead isn't large enough to challenge _Code Lyoko_'s :D

Comment: @DragandDrop Huntik was created by Iginio Straffi (Rainbow studio), who created the Winx too, so the two series have some artistic DNA in common.

Comment: [This question is asked a *lot*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=huntik)

Comment: Thank you very much  Jenayah 