# Anime that has pendant/necklace that transform to monsters, he has a pendant to a green one that has wings that fuse with him

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime that has pendant/necklace that transform to monsters, he has a pendant to a green one that has wings that fuse with him.

He also goes through adventures and find other necklaces one of them is a Basilisk.

Comment: Hi there. That's a bit terse at the moment - could you please check out [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? "summoning monsters" anime are pretty common, I think both _Magi-Nation_ and _Huntik_ at least have such green monsters and basilisks. [_Huntik_ does, at least](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgbz.jpg).

Comment: @Jenayah - More details would always be nice, (did the characters use weapons or only transform to fight, etc.) but I feel like there can't be too many shows out there that have a character searching for necklaces that **transform** him into a creature. Both of those shows you mention don't look like there is any transformation happening. Magic necklaces are common, as is beast/creature transformation, but is the combination that common as well?

Comment: @Odin1806 tbh the phrasing is a bit unclear as well, what's transformed? Character? Necklace? Do the wings fuse with a character or a monster? I quoted MN and _Huntik_ because they're the ones I think about when reading "necklaces summon stuff", and they have a wide variety of monsters, but couldn't be sure they got that, no, otherwise I'd have put it into an answer :)

Comment: @Jenayah - Fair points. Good grammar can be difficult to come by around here unfortunately due to ESL situations and etc... I just think the question has a decent amount of specificity to get some useful answers if the right person sees it. That's all!

Comment: @Jenayah I  kinda guess he was talking about the Kipperin fusion... If Kenny confirms that this is indeed the case, we could probably do some editing on the question to make it a little more readable.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that "he has a pendant to a green one that has wings that fuse with him" I am betting you are referencing "**Huntik: Secrets & Seekers**", which actually **isn't** an anime but an Italian animated television series instead, originally aired in 2009.

[image: Powerbonded Kipperin fusion]

This is the powerbonded fusion between the Titan [Kipperin](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Kipperin) and Lok Lambert, one of the protagonist of the show. As you can see, green is indeed a predominant color in the creature design.

Other details kinda match too.

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.[4] Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.
>   *(original quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers#Series_overview))*

As you can see, Titans - who are summoned from necklace-like amulets - are indeed a main theme of the show (toy replica of the amulets were actually sold when the show was first aired, so you could say this was probably intended to become a merchandise-driven series).
Also worth noticing that not only [King Basilisk](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/King_Basilisk) is an actual Titan in the show - he is one of the main Titans used by Zhalia, one of the other main characters, so your memories about "a Basilisk" are motivated.