# Looking for kids cartoon about magic beast in stones and collecting them

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This cartoon is set in our world. So there are four main characters. There is a blonde teen, a girl, and the old mentor. They went around to ruins, collecting these stones with beasts inside of them. One of the things was that there were three creatures that, if put in the same room, would summon something like God. One of the creatures that was used to summon was a hippo with the world on its back. I think it was on Netflix. One of the episodes was about Ceres Island where they had everything they needed.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Was the island literally named "Ceres Island"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarification that this is set in our world, and involves ruins, might this be *[Huntik: Seekers and Secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)*?

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit.
>
> Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.
>
> In season two, an ancient and evil group known as the Blood Spiral reveals itself and seeks to summon evil and destructive beings known as the Nullifiers. This will have ramifications for everyone, with the Blood Spirals being linked to the destruction of Sophie's remaining family, the descendants of the powerful Lord Casterwill. A new hero, Den Fears, joins the Huntik team as Zhalia goes undercover within the Blood Spiral. A new set of Legendary Titans are uncovered, but their discovery only heralds the resurrection of the Blood Spiral's founder, the Betrayer.

One of the things they seek are the three [Legendary Titans](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Legendary_Titans).

> The Legendary Titans are an incredibly rare, powerful type of Titan which were originally controlled by Lord Casterwill and his family and whose Rings and Amulets were later hidden with greater safeguards than the Amulets of any other Titans. The Legendary Titans find their places in the legends of many ancient civilizations and were sometimes considered gods. If a Seeker attempts to use a Legendary Titan without the Amulet of Will or without passing the proper Casterwill test, they may be put under a powerful curse. Three Legendary Titans, Tao, Behemoth, and Araknos, are involved in a ritual to summon Overlos from the Amulet of Will.

There are several islands in the show. [Madea's Island](https://huntik.fandom.com/wiki/Madea_Island) is apparently covered with illusions, but I don't see any [Lotus Eater](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine) scenarios mentioned.

The main character is indeed blond. There are two girls, and an older fellow, although he is not a mentor.

[image: Splash image for Huntik: Seekers and Secrets]

### Season 1 Opening

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are looking for *[Magi-Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_(TV_series))*

[image: Splash screen of Magi-Nation]

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combatting the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

The Dreamstones are associated with summoning the Dream Creatures, and can be used to summon Agram. Or you could be referencing the [Hyrens](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Hyrens), powerful Dream Creatures that can merge to summon the the [Final Hyren](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Hyren). Not matching is that Tony, while blonde in the original source material (a card game), was a brunette in the cartoon. Also, while it showed up on the WB, and was later streamed on Tubi, [it does not seem to have been a Netflix show](https://www.netflixtvseries.com/tv/14074/magi-nation).

The Island episode is likely "[Eye of the Storm](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2917304/)" from Season 2.

> Blown ashore by a powerful storm, the Final Dreamers find themselves stranded on the strange void energy island. While trying to get off the island battling against unpredictable magical results, the bickering group must find a way to work together in order to be successful.

### Show Opening

Comment: This was the one I thought of too, partly because it's _always_ Magi-Nation. :)

Comment: Or *Chaotic*. Or *Huntik*. :-D

Comment: I had no idea we'd had 10 IDs for *Chaotic*! (Not all accepted.) Of course you've provided 6 of those all by yourself. :)

Comment: If this is a match, it would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144597/anime-with-gems-that-can-summon-beasts-to-fight-for-the-user-one-is-a-purple-tu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Although, in retrospect, I'm not finding the mentor or the hippo creature with a world on its back.

Comment: No unfortunately its not this show it still in our world and they search ruins to find the stones

Comment: @Bontboy173: Ah, that's a good thing to know, and a good detail to edit into your question. Is magic and/or summoning something known to the general populace?

Comment: @DavidW: Heh, *Huntik*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It's catching up on *Magi-Nation* then, at 19 IDs to 22.  Lots of people must have liked those shows, but just not quite enough to remember their names...

Comment: @DavidW: Sadly, *Earth Star Voyager* has fallen off, probably because it doesn't have a legal method of streaming it (although it's not hard to find it on YouTube). I may have to rewatch that one this weekend with my kid.