# US Cartoon show that aired in 2000s, main character looked for their dad; involves blue, red, orange creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I distinctly remember a cartoon show from the early 2000s - early 2010s, which involved the main character looking for his father, which was the inventor or discoverer of these blue creatures that the main character could summon.

I think they fought against these red creatures antithetical to the blue creatures, but then orange ones appeared in the second season I believe. I also think they found his dad at some point in the show.

Similar animation to Teen Titans

Comment: See also: [Anime with a boy hiring a creature from a stone, meets a man named Dante and starts a journey to collect crystals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta)

Comment: @Valorum I don’t believe that one is it. I vividly remember that the creatures were black, but had blue energy to them. The villains were the same but red or orange.

Comment: Monsuno: Destiny; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG6_WIb55o?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might this be ***[Monsuno](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1579911/)*** (2012-2013)...?

From the [Monsuno Wiki](https://monsuno.fandom.com/wiki/Chase_Suno):

> Chase Suno wakes one morning to find his scientist father gone. A legendary scientist, Jeredy had solved a timeless mystery.
>
> But not before he left his only son a special gift, a powerful guardian in dangerous times – a Monsuno. And not just any Monsuno – the first Monsuno Jeredy reanimated, and the means to control it.
>
> Chase Suno is now on a mission to master the battle potential of his Monsuno in order to protect himself, to build a team of like-minded Monsuno “Controllers,” and to find his missing father.

The main character, Chase Suno, learns about battle creatures called Monsuno while searching for his missing father, a scientist.

As shown around the 15:11 mark in the video below, the first episode of season 1 features a battle between a blue Monsuno summoned by Chase and a red Monsuno summoned by an antagonist.

As shown around the 10:44 mark in the video below, the first episode of season 2 features a battle between a group of blue Monsuno summoned by the heroes and a group of orange Monsuno summoned by the antagonists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Slugterra (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2548200/)?

It is about a boy searching for his father, and he has small creatures named "slugs" that he can fire out of a gun and transform into larger creatures. The missing father also had the ability to use the slugs. The bad guys have slugs that have been "ghouled" which is signified with a red glow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that the [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/265908/122024) was marked as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by the OP (as denoted by the green tick next to it), which indicates that the OP believes that answer is correct.