TV show that had a Pokemon-like mechanic except monsters were found inside relics
back in 2016-2017, there was this Pokemon rip-off that I watched just for the fun of it tbh after 1st episode I knew it was not one it was on Netflix can't find it now tho it went like find artifacts, artifacts have monsters inside tame monster fight other monsters win and so on there was real death in it tbh that was cool for me at the time. Good luck
edit I think the name was something like hunting or something

Are you thinking of Huntik: Secrets & Seekers?
Quoting from the intro page on the show's fandom wiki:

The series is an action-adventure comedy that follows the team of Lok Lambert, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and mentor Dante Vale around the globe in search of ancient Amulets that can summon powerful beings known as Titans in order to battle the forces of evil.

The show has a YouTube channel where you can watch complete seasons.




If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205076/anime-with-a-boy-hiring-a-creature-from-a-stone-meets-a-man-named-dante-and-sta

@FuzzyBoots It would be a duplicate of a lot of questions :D, but I agree that is the correct dupe target.
